# How to profile performance under load?

Tags: java, performance, web-applications, profiling, thread-dump

I have a web server that has a few requests performing poorly under heavy load.  I tried using the regular tried and tested techniques, but they have various issues.

**Attempted techniques**

1. Sampling/trace profiling in Yourkit

   - I couldn't use a profiler under load as it was only a few particular requests that were performing poorly
   - Just testing a single request doesn't reproduce the performance problem
2. Thread dumps

   - I attempted thread dumps at fixed intervals, but if the interval was large it was difficult to tell what was actually slow, and if the interval was short it affected the performance characteristics of the server too much

How do I profile performance of a **single request** while the server is under load?

Comment: APM(Application performance management) tool, like jennifer, appDynamics... etc, looks more fit for your situation than profiler. profiler is designed to tune limited requests but APM is designed to monitor and manage system's performance.

Comment: @fglez Its not a particular application container.  The problem is in our code.

Comment: @dgregory APM doesn't help me because I am not trying to figure out overall performance and I actually have a single poorly performing request and need to dig into the details of that.

Comment: I have found [`AspectJ`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) very useful. I can easily trace entry and exit into methods and drill down to the hotspots comparatively quickly. Then I can even change the implementation without having to go through a full compile/build/deploy cycle.

Comment: @Pyrolistical Different servers (especially if propietary) have different monitoring/debugging/tracing mechanisms which may help you.

Comment: If the problem does not occur for individual requests but only manifests under load you may have a lock contention issue. YourKit has a tab for profiling contention that can help highlight the contended locks in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.spf4j.org, I use this library to do continuous profiling in java with minimal overhead...
there is api to monitor execution of your code with minimal performance impact as well
I have recently  added new visualization for app profiles: http://blogs.zoltran.com
get the latest version from trunk and try it out!

cheers